# Can I prevent my toolbaritem from being placed in the new menu panel?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Firefox 29 will feature the new (and somewhat controversial) [Australis](https://blog.mozilla.org/ux/2013/11/australis-is-landing-in-firefox-nightly/) interface. This new interface features a menu panel, replacing the application's main menu button from previous releases (see the Mozilla UX blog post [why what is where](https://blog.mozilla.org/ux/2013/12/whywhatiswhere/) for more).

One of the challenging things about this new menu for add-on designers like myself, is that **add-ons can be added to the menu panel**, in addition to their usual spot on toolbars. For a toolbar-oriented add-on like I maintain (a search toolbar with a number of controls), this makes little sense.

**Question:** Is there a way I can prevent my `toolbaritem` element from being moved to the menu panel area? I don't mind it living on a toolbar (where I intend), or in the customize palette (if the user chooses to hide it for some reason), but it shouldn't live in the new menu panel. Not only is there no room for my extension there, but living in that menu makes no sense from a UI perspective. I know I can hide my `toolbaritem` in that position with CSS, but I'd ideally like to prevent the user from moving it there at all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you absolutely can. Just don't add it to the pallete. You can probably do it in xul overlay but I only know how to do for boostrap in run time, create your toolbaritem then get the id of the container you want to append your toolbar item to then append it. It will not be movable. (I think, this is the case for non-australis)

Comment: Unfortunately, I want my toolbar items to be movable to some degree. Just not movable into the new menu panel.

Comment: It might be movable try it out. If it's not then if you want it movable to some custom degree you'll have to add your own drag event listeners and tell it where all it can be custom moved.